# How can we avoid MapPartition related issues?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val counts = parsed.mapPartitions(iter => {
  iter.flatMap(point => {
    println("points"+point) 
    point.indices.map(i => i,point(i)))
  })
}).countByValue() 
val count = parsed.mapPartitions(iter => {
  iter.flatMap(point => {
    println("pointsssss" + point.deep)
    point.indices.map(i => (i, point(i)))
  }) 
}).countByValue()
```

When I execute `count.foreach(println)`, I also get output from `counts`. How can I avoid this problem ?

Comment: It is not exactly clear what your problem is, maybe you could edit your question ?

Comment: Unrelated: you can use `point.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)` instead of `point.indices.map(i => (i, point(i)))`.

Comment: " also get out from counts."  It's not clear what you mean. Please clarify

Comment: count and counts are two variables .Both have some values. My problem is I only print count.foreach(println). not used counts.foreach(println).But when I executed these lines print statement in count also showing

Comment: Actual problem is when a code having more than one mapPartition.It execute with out a call to that piece of code

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see both print statements is that `countByValue` is itself an action and not a transformation, and it triggers evaluation of the RDD (in this case, both of them). From the docs:

> def countByValue(): Map[T, Long]
>
> Return the count of each unique value in this RDD as a map of (value, count) pairs. The final combine step happens locally on the master, equivalent to running a single reduce task.

Your next code, `count.foreach(println)` happens thus outside of Spark, in normal Scala Collections, in the master node.

Check the logic if this is not the behavior you want, I have the suspicion that you want `countByKey()` instead (also an action).